# Is it possible to parse a particular XML using DOM parser in Android?

Tags: android, xml

The below format is the response from the server. I am trying to parse this by using DOM but getting the exception saying "only one root element is allowed".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <responseCode>2000</responseCode>
  <responseText>Success</responseText>
  <response>
    <response1>on</response1>
    <response1>on</response1>
    <response1>on</response1>
    <response1>on</response1>
    <response1>on</response1>
  </response>
  <response>
    <response1>on</response1>
    <response1>on</response1>
    <response1>on</response1>
    <response1>on</response1>
    <response1>on</response1>
  </response>
  <response>
    <response1>on</response1>
    <response1>on</response1>
    <response1>on</response1>
    <response1>on</response1>
    <response1>on</response1>
  </response>
```

Comment: yes.but you are missing a root tag. also recommend using xmlpullparser http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Comment: @Raghunandan:Hi thanks for the response if you have the sample code please  send me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be much easier parsing using the `XmlPullParser`, and much more efficient too

Ex. XML file content (saved in external storage as code.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<countries>
 <country>
   <name>Iran</name>
   <phonecode>+98</phonecode>
   <code>IRI</code>
 </country>
 <country>
   <name>United State</name>
   <phonecode>+1</phonecode>
   <code>USA</code>
 </country>
</countries>
```

**Lets begin parsing it**

1. First create a Helper class

   ```
   import android.util.Xml;
   import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
   import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStream;

   public class XmlDataParseHelper {

   private XmlPullParser parser;
   private static final String NULL = null;

   /**
    * 
    * @param in
    * @throws XmlPullParserException
    * @throws IOException
    * @throws IllegalArgumentException
    */
   public XmlDataParseHelper(InputStream in) throws XmlPullParserException,
           IOException, IllegalArgumentException {
       try {
           parser = Xml.newPullParser();
           parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
           parser.setInput(in, null);
           parser.nextTag();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

   /**
    * 
    * @return XmlPullParser
    */
   public XmlPullParser getParser() {
       return parser;
   }

   /**
    * 
    * @param parser
    * @param tag
    * @return String
    * @throws IOException
    * @throws XmlPullParserException
    */
   public static String readTag(XmlPullParser parser, String tag)
           throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
       String tagData = "";
       parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, NULL, tag);
       if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
           tagData = parser.getText();
           parser.nextTag();
       }
       parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, NULL, tag);
       return tagData;
   }

   /**
    * 
    * @param parser
    * @param tag
    * @param attributeName
    * @return String
    * @throws IOException
    * @throws XmlPullParserException
    */
   public static String readAttribute(XmlPullParser parser, String tag,
           String attributeName) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
       parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, NULL, tag);
       String attributeData = parser.getAttributeValue(NULL, attributeName);
       parser.nextTag();
       parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, NULL, tag);
       return attributeData;
   }

   }
   ```
2. Read the xml file as

   ```
   public InputStream readFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException,
           IOException {
   //check external storage present
   // else throw new IOException();

   return new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
           + "/" + fileName);
   }
   ```
3. Pass the InputStream to another method which initializes the XMLPullParser object

   ```
    public void readXmlFile(String fileName) {
    try {
       if (fileName.isEmpty())
       throw new NullPointerException();
       readData(new XmlDataParseHelper(readFile(fileName)).getParser());
    } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
   ```
4. Atlast parse the `XMLPullParser object` as

   ```
     public void readData(XmlPullParser parser)
               throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
   int eventType = parser.getEventType();
   String tagName = "";
   Log.w("Developer", "Reading file...");
   while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
       switch (eventType) {
           case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT :
               Log.w("Developer", "Reading backup file...");
               break;
           case XmlPullParser.START_TAG :
               tagName = parser.getName();
               if (tagName.equals("countries")) {
                   Log.w("XMLParse", "Start TAG countries");
                   // do something when countries tag starts
               }
               if (tagName.equals("country")) {
                   Log.w("XMLParse", "Start TAG country");
                   // do some when country tag starts
               } else if (tagName.equals("name")) {
                   // read tag value using XmlDataParseHelper class
                   String countryName = XmlDataParseHelper.readTag(parser,
                                   "name");
                   Log.w("XmlParser", "Country name : "+countryName);
               } else if (tagName.equals("phonecode")) {
                   String countryPhoneCode = 
                                 XmlDataParseHelper.readTag(parser,"phonecode");
                   Log.w("XmlParser", "Country Phone code : "+countryPhoneCode);
               } else if (tagName.equals("code")) {
                   String countryCode = 
                                XmlDataParseHelper.readTag(parser, "code");
                   Log.w("XmlParser", "Country code name : "+countryCode); 
               }
           break;
           case XmlPullParser.END_TAG :
               tagName = parser.getName();
               if (tagName.equals("countries")) {
                     // do something when counties tag is close.
               }           
           break;
       }
       eventType = parser.next();
   }
   Log.w("Developer", "File parsing complete...");
    }
   ```
5. To read a file just call the method `readXmlFile(String fileName)` in an AsyncTask with the name of file stored in the External Storage.

The whole android working example code is here https://gist.github.com/rachitrm/7810837 or fork the project http://www.github.com/rachitrm/rm-xmlparser/

Comment: hi please see my post once my xml response is not having root elements is it possible to parse using xml pull parser

Comment: @user3110163 yes, try the above code, as the XmlPullParser parses on basis of start document and end document. download the project and try it... ! I am also testing your code.

Comment: thnakyou soo much i will try it

Answer (score 2):

That is invalid XML. The response should be as follows:

```
<root>
  <responseCode>2000</responseCode>
  <responseText>Success</responseText>
  <response>
    <response1>on</response1>
    <response1>on</response1>
    <response1>on</response1>
    <response1>on</response1>
    <response1>on</response1>
  </response>
  <response>
    <response1>on</response1>
    <response1>on</response1>
    <response1>on</response1>
    <response1>on</response1>
    <response1>on</response1>
  </response>
  <response>
    <response1>on</response1>
    <response1>on</response1>
    <response1>on</response1>
    <response1>on</response1>
    <response1>on</response1>
  </response>
</root>
```

Comment: thank you for response is it possible to parse my xml